# Upgrade Spring (2.5.5 to 4.0.2) and hibernate (3.2.6 to 3.6.9) version

Tags: spring, hibernate, jpa, persistence

I have been migrating my application from the spring (2.5.5 to 4.0.2.RELEASE) and Hibernate (3.2.6 to 3.6.9). From Spring ORM JPA migration I have faced this issue Just want to make myself correct is that my way is right or the version is the problem for all of this issue.

Multiplepersistence loading issue

```
Error creating bean with name 'something' defined in class path resource [spring/test-persistenceContext.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Conflicting persistence unit definitions for name
```

I resolved this by

1. I removed the "persistenceUnitName" defined in the test-persistenceContext.xml for the bean class "org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean". 
   2.I have made the "persistenceUnitManager" property to get the "DefaultPersistenceUnitManager" by using ref and the "mergepersistenceUnitPostProcessor class" which impl the PersistenceUnitPostProcessor interface.

Then it went smooth there. But its gives me error in building the entities.

1. Its keep saying the composite Ids defined which shouldn't use `@Id` where the `@EmbededId` using in the entities class and the @Id's are defined in the key/Id classes which is normally  using the getId() to get the respective id's. I am removed all the @Id from the ID/Entity classes.
2. `@ManyToOne()` relationship the `joincolumns` are not able to identify I removed the `@joincolumns` annot to fix the issue.

Now i totally stuck in the below error

```
Error creating bean with name 'something' defined in class path resource [spring/test-persistenceContext.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.MappingException: Foreign key (column names[1,2,3,4]) must have same number of columns as the referenced primary key (column names [1,2,4]).
```

Dont know I have fixed for one but its keep on arising like this issues.
Please let me know if you need move stack trace details on this.

```
public class AccountEntityKey extends AbstractEntityKey {
 private String accountId;
}

@MappedSuperclass
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.PROPERTY)
public abstract class AbstractEntityKey implements EntityKey {

    private String status;
}

public class Account extends AbstractAccount {
@Transient
    private String accountId;

    @Transient
    private String status;

  @Override
    @EmbeddedId
    @AttributeOverrides( {
            @AttributeOverride(name = "accountId", column = @Column(name = "ACCT_ID", unique = false, nullable = false, insertable = true, updatable = false, length = 32)),
            @AttributeOverride(name = "status", column = @Column(name = "ACCT_STA_TYP", unique = false, nullable = false, insertable = true, updatable = false, length = 10)) })

    public AccountEntityKey getId() {
        return (id != null) ? (AccountEntityKey) super.getId() : new          AccountEntityKey(accountId,
                status);}
}

    public class AccountParty {

      /**
         * @return the account
         * (cascade = {}, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)    
         * @JoinColumns( {
                @JoinColumn(name = "ACCT_ID", unique = false, nullable = false, insertable      = false, updatable = false),
                @JoinColumn(name = "ACCT_STA_TYP", unique = false, nullable = false, insertable = false, updatable = false) })
         */
        @ManyToOne
        public Account getAccount() {
            return account;
        }

}
```

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [spring/test-persistenceContext.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.MappingException: Foreign key (FKEC0DF9EF331D3E16:CLIENT_ACCOUNT_SERVICE [ACCT_ID,ACCT_PTY_STA_TYP,ACCT_ROLE_TYP,ACCT_STA_TYP,PTY_ID,PTY_ROLE_TYP,PTY_STA_TYP])) must have same number of columns as the referenced primary key (ACCOUNT_PARTY [ACCT_ID,ACCT_PTY_STA_TYP,ACCT_ROLE_TYP,PTY_ID,PTY_ROLE_TYP,PTY_STA_TYP])
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1553)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:539)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:475)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:304)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:228)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:300)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:195)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:973)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:750)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:482)
    at org.springframework.test.AbstractSingleSpringContextTests.createApplicationContext(AbstractSingleSpringContextTests.java:216)
    at org.springframework.test.AbstractSingleSpringContextTests.loadContextLocations(AbstractSingleSpringContextTests.java:192)
    at org.springframework.test.AbstractSingleSpringContextTests.loadContext(AbstractSingleSpringContextTests.java:172)
    at org.springframework.test.AbstractSpringContextTests.getContext(AbstractSpringContextTests.java:133)
    at org.springframework.test.AbstractSingleSpringContextTests.setUp(AbstractSingleSpringContextTests.java:101)
    at junit.framework.TestCase.runBare(TestCase.java:125)
    at org.springframework.test.ConditionalTestCase.runBare(ConditionalTestCase.java:79)
    at junit.framework.TestResult$1.protect(TestResult.java:106)
    at junit.framework.TestResult.runProtected(TestResult.java:124)
    at junit.framework.TestResult.run(TestResult.java:109)
    at junit.framework.TestCase.run(TestCase.java:118)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.junit3.JUnit3TestReference.run(JUnit3TestReference.java:130)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:467)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:683)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:390)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:197)
Caused by: org.hibernate.MappingException: Foreign key (FKEC0DF9EF331D3E16:CLIENT_ACCOUNT_SERVICE [ACCT_ID,ACCT_PTY_STA_TYP,ACCT_ROLE_TYP,ACCT_STA_TYP,PTY_ID,PTY_ROLE_TYP,PTY_STA_TYP])) must have same number of columns as the referenced primary key (ACCOUNT_PARTY [ACCT_ID,ACCT_PTY_STA_TYP,ACCT_ROLE_TYP,PTY_ID,PTY_ROLE_TYP,PTY_STA_TYP])
    at org.hibernate.mapping.ForeignKey.alignColumns(ForeignKey.java:112)
    at org.hibernate.mapping.ForeignKey.alignColumns(ForeignKey.java:95)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.secondPassCompileForeignKeys(Configuration.java:1835)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.originalSecondPassCompile(Configuration.java:1756)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.secondPassCompile(Configuration.java:1423)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildMappings(Configuration.java:1375)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.Ejb3Configuration.buildMappings(Ejb3Configuration.java:1519)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.EventListenerConfigurator.configure(EventListenerConfigurator.java:193)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.Ejb3Configuration.configure(Ejb3Configuration.java:1100)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.Ejb3Configuration.configure(Ejb3Configuration.java:689)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(HibernatePersistence.java:73)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.createNativeEntityManagerFactory(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:336)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:318)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1612)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1549)
    ... 26 more
```

Comment: you need to paste Class/ configuration files to check.

Comment: Please find the post is updated i have pasted the code for entity classes and the corresponding id classes. Stack traced also attached.

Comment: You need to check PK and FK in tables first. What are PK/FK in ACCOUNT_PARTY and CLIENT_ACCOUNT_SERVICE tables?

Comment: Its a upgrade activity where the PK referred directly with Id annot and composite id/Foreign key are referred with the @EmbeddedId in the entity class. From the code perspective i dont see much difference in the sense Its perfect.as you see it in above.